# ::ng-deep override the elements from components to another component

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have a main.scss that has the common selector and properties for all components.
In a particular component I need to "override" some properties of main.scss.

I use

```
::ng-deep body .ui-datepicker:not(.ui-datepicker-inline) {
    top: 0px !important;
 }
```

and this is the same main.scss props

```
body .ui-datepicker:not(.ui-datepicker-inline) {
   border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
   box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
   top: -150px !important; 
   z-index: 10130 !important; 
}
```

It works when I enter on my component, but the problem is that the ::ng-deep applies the new property when I change the components and don't re-apply the main.scss properties.
How can I fix it?

Comment: that mean if I change page/component it override my main.scss properties

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your component scss.

```css
:host ::ng-deep .ui-datepicker:not(.ui-datepicker-inline) {
    top: 0px !important;
 }
```

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work in the component. Seems doesn't apply the top: 0px but mantain the top: -150px

Comment: Can you remove important from top: -150px !important; ?